# How to add a column in R using information from existing columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

In my current data set, I have a column for state names and then a few other columns with some health information for each state. Basically I want to add a Region column that says which region each state is in. Here's what I've tried so far:

However, I get the error for the shorter object length not being a multiple of the longer object length. I know this means that there is differing length of each vector so it won't apply the argument. I'm essentially trying to say "if state name = one of the states in this item, apply the appropriate region to it". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `%in%` as `==` only checks for the first value in your vector:

```
#Code
cleandata$Region[cleandata$statename %in% south] <- "South"
cleandata$Region[cleandata$statename %in% midwest] <- "Midwest"
```

Comment: @IsaacNiedzwiecki two reason: 1. It might be upper and lower cases so that comparison is not reached. 2. there might be white spaces. Try applying `cleandata$Region<-tolower(trimws(cleandata$Region))` and also do the same for the vectors like `south<-tolower(trimws(south))`

Comment: Yeah it seems that there were spaces after some of the states in the state name column. Thanks for the tips